# Solve the modulo of a high-raised number

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need some help with this problem:

$$439^{n} \mod p = 67  \mod  p $$

How to calculate the value of `n` , p is a prime number let's assume `p` be **10^9+7** ?

Comment: Do you mean: solve
$$439^n\equiv67\pmod p$$
for $n$? I suppose that rather depends on what $p$ is.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  p is prime number and it's known.

Comment: Sorry, but it’s still not clear what you’re asking. Is $p$ a particular prime that you’re keeping secret from us, or is $p$ a general prime?

Comment: @Lubin `p` is a general prime.

Comment: It's unlikely you'll be able to get a general formula for $n$ expressed in terms of $p$, if that's what you're asking for. Although I don't know what the best answer is, I think it would be more realistic to ask for an algorithm that works for a specific, known, large value of $p$.

Comment: If you are working with a large prime, then this looks to me like a discrete logarithm problem.

Comment: According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Algorithms), this kind of problem is considered "computationally intractable," with the best algorithms known taking time roughly proportional to $\sqrt{p}$. However, according to the same article, the problem can be solved efficiently in quantum computing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the value of $p$, the closest thing to a general solution would be this:

Find some value $m$ such that $439^m\equiv 67\pmod p$. Now, let $d$ be the smallest positive integer such that $439^d\equiv 1\pmod d$. The set of $n$ such that $439^n\equiv 67\pmod p$ is exactly the set of positive integers $n$ for which $n\equiv m\pmod d$.

Some things to note are:

- $m$ doesn't always exist
- $d$ only exists when $p\nmid 439$
- $d$ (if it exists) is a divisor of $\varphi(p)=p-1$

As you can see, we can easily generate an infinite amount of solutions once we have one (and the value of $d$), but finding that first solution (or finding $d$ for that matter) is a case of a very hard problem, known as the [discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm)